# parseFloat() vs. parseDouble()

Tags: java, string, floating-point, double

I am trying the code below to convert string to float and double but getting different results.

### Code:

```
 System.out.println(Float.parseFloat("120059389"));
 System.out.println(Double.parseDouble("120059389"));
```

### Output:

```
1.20059392E8
1.20059389E8
```

Could somebody explain me why I got different result for parsing string in float and double? What are the ranges for float and double?

Comment: This will help:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: Obligatory: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Google "IEEE floating point".  There is a Wikipedia article that explains it all, and isn't too dense.

Answer (score 10):

This is because you're trying to parse a `float` by giving it more digits of precision than it can handle.  The ["ulp" (unit in last place) of a `float`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ulp%28float%29) that big is `8.0`, but the ["ulp" for  a `double`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ulp%28double%29) that big is still reasonably small.  That is, at that magnitude, the closest possible `float` values differ by `8`, but the closest `double` values, with more precision, differ by far less.

```
System.out.println(Math.ulp(120059389f));
System.out.println(Math.ulp(120059389d));
```

This prints:

```
8.0
1.4901161193847656E-8
```

So the `Float` parser must use the closest `float` to the true value of `120059389`, which happens to be `1.20059392E8`.

Comment: Here is the technical spec from the JLS: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3

Answer (score 7):

The difference lies in the fact that `Double` and `Float` store numbers differently.

With Single and Double precision, allowing `Double` to give *Double* the amount of precision the `Float` can handle.

So the simple answer is that because of `Float`'s limited memory in comparison to `Double` information is lost upon conversion of numbers out of the range `Float` can handle.

- `Float`  : 32-bit Numbers
- `Double` : 64-bit Numbers

So in the conversion some information is lost when converting to the `Float` because it is truncated.

Generally...

`Float` stores numbers as 1 bit for the sign (`-/+`), 8 bits for the Exponent, and 23 bits for the fraction.

`Double` stores numbers as 1 bit for the sign (`-/+`), 8 bits for the Exponent, and 53 bits for the fraction.

When you convert your number `120059389 = 111001001111111010111111101b` has 27 bits worth of information which can be covered by the `Double`'s 53 bit allowence, but not by the `Float`'s 23 bit allowance, and the data is truncated at the least significant end.

The conversion will round the number to the nearest representable number using 23 bits `1.20059392 = 111001001111111011000000000b` and the exponent will handle the rest of the expansion.

Answer (score 1):

The earlier links and answers give good technical answers.  The 'laymans' answer is that a float is 32 bits and a double is 64 bits.  Some of those bits are used for the number and some are used for the exponent.  The number you put in your code simply had too many digits for the 32 bit 'float'.   The 64 bit 'double' has more bits and can be more precise with larger numbers.

The same concept holds for even larger numbers when you reach the limits of a 64 bit double and need 128 bits of precision.